# Calculate pull-up resistor for phototransistors

Tags: sensor, pullup, phototransistor

I have made a sensor which uses six [IR phototransistors](http://www.ligitek.com/datasheet/lpt3323-pf.pdf), three per sensor block, opposite it is a matched IR diode(940nm). This is in turn connected to a MCU.

The function of the circuit is an airrifle chronograph, the circuit generates a signal when a pellet passes over one of the sets of three transistors, thus breaking the circuit giving a pulse. Look at the first image on the linked page [here.](http://www.network54.com/Forum/79537/thread/1312722077/New+Updated+2-0+Version+of+Poor+Man%27s+Chrono)

## Problem

Firstly the device is detecting an object with a *4.7mm* cross section passing between sensors, the original application used an audio port and the internal amplifier and some pull ups to create a pulse for each crossing of the sensor. When I added a external pull-up and measured the voltage, only a small change was visible. This yielded results such as \$ 0.4v < VOut < 0.9v\$, which obviously will not be picked up by an interrupt. I concluded that I would need to use a compartor to give a clean signal for the input to the MCU, this would be a standard circuit with hysteresis non-inverting.

***Question:*** How do I calculate the needed pull-up resistor to give me a voltage range of 1.5 - 3V from a 5V supply with 6 phototransistors(linked above). This will be feed into the comparator circuit.

I know that transistors can be simplified to equivalent resistors but I do not know how to determine them for a phototransistor, I am assuming one can do this so as to find a pull-up.

---

**Edit**

The [datasheet](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/201407061516067600.pdf) for the IR led.

Here is a snapshot of the wave form from the audio port and software used to read the signal:

[image]

Each spike is a break of a three set sensor of the six.

Comment: Why are they all in series?  Your total current will be the current of the least illuminated phototransistor.  (5V may not be enough bias... but I don't use photo-transistors.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your system relies on all the photo-transistors being illuminated when no object is passing in front. With 6 photo-transistors in series and all of them being strongly illuminated, the "on" voltage of the group is 6 x 0.4V = 2.4 volts.

The 0.4V figure comes from the data sheet, \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$ = 0.4V at 20mW/sq cm illumination.

Any device switching off (due to a blockage) will cause the signal to rise to about 5V. So, the basic system you have cannot be guaranteed to generate any change in signal voltage greater than 2.6 volts p-p and this is with fully illuminated devices. Should the IR diode that does the illumination not be producing a power output of at least 20mW/sq cm at the photo-transistors, the individual "on" voltages will be somewhat greater than 0.4 volts and this might be (say) 0.8 volts.

The impact of this is that the change in signal voltage seen at the output will be 5 volts - (6 x 0.8 volts) = 0.2 volts.

I believe you need to sort out this problem first before deciding on the value of resistor. Look at the volt drop across one of the photo-transistors (not in the group but separately powered via a load resistor) and see what it is when illuminated.

I'll also add that the data sheet is not very helpful when it comes to stating what the "illuminated" collector current is - there seems to be several figures and no explanation of what conditions these different figures apply to.

Comment: +1 for being useful, I have 940nm IR diodes facing the phototransistors. I have seen the output voltage you describe too.

Comment: I was going to deal with the low voltages given by the circuit to control a comparator so as to get clean high or low for a micro.

Comment: I think before I can give further advice you should show a picture of the signal and give a link to the IR emitter.

Comment: ok I'll do that, would you like a link or a link edited into the ques

Comment: I have added the link and a waveform

Comment: Are you aware that the IR transmitter is quite a tight beam - is this projecting onto all the photo-transistors adequately. Also, re the picture of the signal I need an oscilloscope picture of the signal from the output of one device.

Comment: There is one IR led to three phototransistors, 100mm between transmitter and phototransistors, all three are right next to each other. Unfortunately I dont have an Oscilloscope, nor do I have a scope picture :(, sorry

Comment: I have measured the voltage drop with an IR led pointed at the phototransistor, 10k load, the V drop is .10 across the phototransistor, 4.5V when no IR is present.

Comment: Was the led at the correct distance for the normal set up?

Comment: yes those are the readings for the distance in set up, its actually 75mm

Comment: OK so if all 6 transistors are identical then you could expect the peak to peak signal to be from 0.6 volts to 4.5 volts BUT wait.... ambient light will cause each transistor to conduct and thus reduce that obscured-unobscured signal. Also, the object that passes in front may not completely obscure one transistor thus it never really goes dark? I might also add that the measurements you have made are at odds with the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you are really trying to do since your circuit makes no sense.  Some issues:

The photodiodes are oriented so that they operate in photocell mode, but yet you are deliberately applying bias.

Do you really want all the diodes in series?  This effectively causes a AND function.  They all have to be activated to produce a output signal.  This is a bit less certain in photocell mode, depending on the impedance the string is loaded with.

If you do run the photodiodes in leakage mode (flip them around relative to how you have them now), you will only get a small signal.

As with using any electronic part, you have to actually **read the datasheet** of the part, then use it accordingly in a circuit.  The datasheet should tell you, among other things, what the reverse leakage will be for various light levels.

Comment: if you read the red writing next to the diodes and the question you will notice that I am using PHOTOTRANSITORS

Comment: @RSM: If you read the schematic, you will notice that photodiodes are specified.  If you want to show phototransistors, show phototransistors.  No, showing one part and then saying it's another is NOT acceptable.

Comment: I could not find the phototransitors

Comment: Quick question Olin if you care to respond to me, if you were disgruntled with the lack of consistency in may question why didn't you post a comment?

Comment: Would you have objected if RSM had used NPN transistors without base connections, and a note to the side that they were phototransistors?

Comment: @W5VO: NPN transistors with no base connections and little arrows indicating illumination would have been OK. Notes to the side can *add* information, but should never be relied on to correct something in the schematic. The schematic must be correct on its own. In this case the photodiodes shown and the phototransistors actually in use have quite different electrical properties, to the point where the circuit as posted made no sense.